# Can someone please explain the below code and the following query too

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I did use the manual but I am unable to get all the options together to understand what the above code is actually doing.

```
awk -v v='"' 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=v}{gsub(",","",$2);print }'  \
  ${SOURCE_LOCATION}/TEMP1_$file_name>${SOURCE_FILE_LOCATION}/TEMP2_$file_name
```

When do we have to use the curly brackets in a code after the '$' and when not to. Please explain. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: This question really should have been two different questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command would remove all the commas in the second field.  The field separator being the quote character `"` (as specified by `FS`).

For example, the following string:

```
something "string, with, commas" something "else, here, and more"
```

would be transformed to:

```
something "string with commas" something "else, here, and more"
```

The significance of `{}` in variable names has been well explained by @Joni.

The input is read from the file `${SOURCE_LOCATION}/TEMP1_$file_name` and output is redirected to `${SOURCE_LOCATION}/TEMP2_$file_name`.

Comment: Is there a way to check the same condition for all the columns of a file and substitute empty space for commas enclosed in double quotes? Really appreciate your help on this

Answer (score 1):

You must use the curly brackets syntax when a variable name is followed by something that's not part of the variable name but could be confused with it. For example, compare

```
hello="Hello"
echo $hello_world
```

with

```
hello="Hello"
echo ${hello}_world
```

The first one outputs an empty line (or the value of the shell variable `hello_world`, if it exists), and the second one outputs `Hello_world`.

In your case they are not necessary because a slash can never be a part of the variable name. Some people prefer to use the brackets to make it clear where the variable begins and where it ends even when they are not required.